# iOS UITests pass on Xcode but fails with xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, uitest

When I run my UITest from XCode they all pass correctly but when I use xcodebuild - some of them fail with error:

```
Failure: UITestBase.swift:63: Failed to get matching snapshot: Lost connection to the application (pid 43193).
```

Currently I'm using 11.6, it did work fine on Xcode 10.x, xcodebuild points to correct Xcode where tests pass from IDE

xcodebuild command that I'm using:

```
xcodebuild clean test -workspace APP.xcworkspace -scheme APPUITests -configuration Release OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS="-DCOCOAPODS -DAPPProdTarget" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11,OS=13.6"
```